# Dropdown submenu do not stay open on hover

Tags: jquery, hover, submenu

I have a dropdown menu with submenu that does fadeIn/Out on hover.  The dropdown does fadeIn and out like I want, and the dropdown submenu does fadeIn / Out like I want.  However, when I go from dropdown to submenu-link it fadeOut and disappears.

I can't really figure out how to solve this issue and keep the submenu open.

HTML:

```
<!-- Dropdown Submenu -->
               <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="has-sub">Trigger 1 <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                       <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                        <a href="#" class="sub-has-sub">Trigger in sub <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>
                           <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                               <li><a href="#">2 Columns</a></li>
                               <li><a href="#">3 Columns</a></li>
                               <li><a href="#">4 Columns</a></li>
                           </ul>
                       </li>
                       <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                       <a href="#" class="sub-has-sub">Trigger in sub 2 <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>
                           <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                               <li><a href="#">2.2 Columns</a></li>
                               <li><a href="#">3.3 Columns</a></li>
                               <li><a href="#">4.4 Columns</a></li>
                           </ul>
                       </li>

                    </ul>
                </li> <!-- /.dropdown -->
                <!-- Dropdown Submenu End -->
```

jQuery

```
$('.dropdown').hover(function() {

      $(this).find('.has-sub').next('ul').stop(true, true).fadeIn("fast");

      }, 
      function() {
        $(this).find('.has-sub').next('ul').stop(true, true).delay(300).fadeOut("fast");

     });

      $('.sub-has-sub').hover(function() {
      $(this).next('ul').stop(true, true).fadeIn("fast");
      $(this).addClass('open');  
      }, 
      function() {
        $(this).next('ul').stop(true, true).delay(300).fadeOut("fast");

     });
```

Comment: Any suggestions please

Comment: Still looking for a solution @Peter? Just stumbled upon this but have dealt with this sort of thing before. http://tinyurl.com/pro8gmn